# canvas drawing multiple objects onto screen. How to mirror some horizontally

Tags: canvas, html5-canvas

[image]

Currently drawing a bunch of little characters onto a canvas. Each human has its individual `draw` method which draws the image onto the canvas.

```
interface Follower{
  this.pos = {x: number, y: number};
  this.moveDir = {x: number, y:number};
  this.update = () => void // gets called on the update method which updates the position slightly
  this.draw = function() {
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false
    const followerImage = 
    canvasDetails.canvases.followersCanvas.assets['followerSpriteSheet']
    followerImage.width = this.width
    followerImage.height = this.height
    ctx.drawImage(followerImage, this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.width, this.height);
}
```

Currently they just glide around the bounds of the grass however, I want them to face the direction they move in.

This can be easily determined by looking at the `human.moveDir.x` value. If it's negative, the sprite should be facing left. And if its positive, it should be facing right.

This is essentially what my code looks like:

```
const loop = () => {
  currentFollowers.forEach(follower => follower.update())
}

const draw = () => {
  currentFollowers.forEach(follower => follower.draw())
}
```

I figured this task would be super easy by just adding a condition within the draw method of each Follower... something like this:

```
follower.draw = function() {
    ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = false
    const followerImage = canvasDetails.canvases.followersCanvas.assets['followerSpriteSheet']
    followerImage.width = this.width
    followerImage.height = this.height
    ctx.save()
    if (follower.moveDir.x < 0) { <-----
      ctx.scale(-1, 1)
    }
    ctx.restore()
    ctx.drawImage(followerImage, this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.width, this.height);
}
```

But this doesnt work. When facing left, the image just disappears. I've tried a couple more things to no avail. Im potentially thinking about having a separate canvas layer that is mirrored by default and drawing the followers that are facing left there.

Would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

After fiddling around it some more, i got it working with this:

```
if (this.moveDir.x < 0) {
    ctx.save()

    ctx.setTransform(-1, 0, 0, 1,this.pos.x + this.width, this.pos.y);

    ctx.drawImage(followerImage, 0, 0)
    ctx.restore()
}
```